# How to use Brackets as my git core.editor on mac osx?

Tags: git, macos

I need help setting up Brackets as my git core.editor.  I cannot find the right code to set this up.

I tried the code:

```
git config --global core.editor brackets
```

When I run the code:

```
error: cannot run brackets: No such file or directory
error: unable to start editor 'brackets'
Please supply the message using either -m or -F option.
```

Comment: Is `brackets` on your  $PATH?

Comment: I am having the exact same problem...